# Issue starting Tomcat 7.0.x from ANT in Windows 2008

Tags: tomcat, ant

I am getting stuck trying to start Tomcat 7.0.x server from ANT in Windows 2008 R2.

This is the code I am using:

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe" spawn="true">
  <env key="CATALINA_HOME" value="${tomcat.home}" />
  <arg line="/C '${tomcat.home}/bin/startup.bat'"/>
</exec>
```

The issue is that although I use spawn set to true, and /C parameter when invoking cmd.exe my build get hanged and never finishes until I stop Tomcat.

Do you know the reason? I have seen many posts here in stackoverflow with similar code that theoretically works fine. Other posts use bash instead of cmd, but as far as I know bash is only in Unix world.

Any help?

Thanks a lot,

Chemi.

Comment: I forgot to mention two details: I am using ANT 1.7.1 executed from Rational Team Concert 4.0.1

Comment: Same behavior with ANT 1.8.1

Comment: It seems it is a defect in the Build Engine used to invoke ANT. I am filling a defect and I will come back here with the results.

Comment: Just to follow if your are interested: https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=249261

Answer (score 0):

well not sure about windows, but based on this discussion ( http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200108.mbox/%3C2D90C2075E27D4118960000629A832E503751900@scooby.corp.bspark.com%3E ) I'd give a try to:

```
<exec dir="${tomcat.home}/bin" executable="start">
    <arg line="startup.bat" />
    <env key="CATALINA_HOME" value="${tomcat.home}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: It seems in Windows 2008 it doesn't work: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamConcertBuild\buildsystem\buildengine\eclipse\fetched_BANNER_WEB\DemoWeb\build"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: intersting, if you run start in command line, does it give you similar output? as based on this (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.10).aspx) start should work for you

Comment: No, from a command line, start starts another command line. But from ANT on Windows 2008 it fails.

Comment: if the other answer doesn't help, try to use ant -verbose switch (as suggested: http://ant.apache.org/problems.html), as it might show you what exactly is beeing run there and maybe try to play around with the command directly from command line and bring it to some working state.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that parametr to check wht is happening under the covers with that option, although as I commented in my original question it seems a defect in the Build Engine I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a portion of my ant script that we've been using for ... ever. It gets used every day in development and we also use it in production to start and stop Tomcat (all on *NIX, though... we have a few devs who simply must run on Microsoft Windows for some reason, and this does not seem to present any problems for them).

There are no problems with hanging that I know of.

```
<exec osfamily="unix" executable="${app.tomcat-home}/bin/catalina.sh">
  <env key="JAVA_HOME" value="${app.java-home}" />
  <env key="JAVA_OPTS" value="${effective.JAVA_OPTS}" />
  <env key="CATALINA_BASE" value="${app.home.dir}" />
  <env key="CATALINA_OPTS" value="${effective.CATALINA_OPTS}" />

  <arg value="start" />
  <arg value="${security-option}" />
</exec>

<!-- Separate script for win32 -->
<exec osfamily="winnt" executable="${app.tomcat-home}/bin/catalina.bat">
  <env key="JAVA_HOME" value="${app.java-home}" />
  <env key="JAVA_OPTS" value="${effective.JAVA_OPTS}" />
  <env key="CATALINA_HOME" value="${app.tomcat-home}" />
  <env key="CATALINA_BASE" value="${app.home.dir}" />
  <env key="CATALINA_OPTS" value="${effective.CATALINA_OPTS}" />

  <arg value="start" />
  <arg value="${security-option}" />
</exec>
```

The definitions of all the properties are left as an exercise for the reader.